# msmq using binaryformatter

Tags: c#, msmq, binaryformatter

I have a component that writes to a Queue (here's the code):

```
using (MessageQueueTransaction transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction())
            {
                transaction.Begin();
                using (var queue = new MessageQueue(@fullQueue, QueueAccessMode.Send))
                {
                    BinaryMessageFormatter formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
                   // XmlMessageFormatter formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Testing) });

                    var testing = new Testing {myBody = string.Format("Hello {0}",Environment.UserName), myMessageText = "Header"};
                    var message = new Message
                    {
                        Body = testing,
                        Label = Environment.MachineName,
                        UseDeadLetterQueue = true,
                        Recoverable = true,
                        Formatter = formatter
                    };
                    queue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);

                } 
                transaction.Commit(); 

            }
```

Now When I run the above 'Testing' is simply a Serializble object with 2 properties on it. If I look at the body of the text on the Queue it looks ok.

Now I have a separate component to read from the queue :

```
 BinaryMessageFormatter formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
       // XmlMessageFormatter formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Testing) });
        MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue(fullQueue, QueueAccessMode.Receive);

        try
        {

            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {

                Message incoming = new Message { Formatter = formatter, AcknowledgeType = AcknowledgeTypes.FullReceive };

                incoming =  msgQ.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3),MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
               // var ttt = incoming.Body;
                MemoryStream mem = (MemoryStream) incoming.BodyStream;
                mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                IFormatter ifm = new BinaryFormatter();
                Testing tt = (Testing)ifm.Deserialize(mem);

                transaction.Complete();
            }

        }
```

Now at the point I'm performing the ifm.Deserialize, It errors with

**Unable to find assembly 'MSMQWrite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'** Where MSMQWrite is the Method name within my write component.

When Writing to the queue I thought I might have to explicitly serialize the object first so on my component that writes I changed my code slightly to be:

```
var testing = new Testing {myBody = string.Format("Hello {0}",Environment.UserName), myMessageText = "Header"};
                    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();

                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    bf.Serialize(mem,testing);

                    var message = new Message
                    {   BodyStream = mem,
                        //Body = testing,
                        Label = Environment.MachineName,
                        UseDeadLetterQueue = true,
                        Recoverable = true,
                        Formatter = formatter
                    };
                    queue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

As you can see I'm setting the BodyStream directly this time, but I still receive the same error when trying to read from the queue.

Comment: Do you have a separate Testing class in each assembly? If you want to use binary formatter then assemblies must be shared (unless you want to _play_ with it, possible, just not easy)

Comment: Yes, the Testing class has been duplicated in both assemblies

Comment: You can't, in C# (contrary, for example, to C++) a class is tied to its assembly. Name isn't enough. You should move it to a shared assembly (or _hacking_ formatter to resolve to **another type**, because a class with same name is another assembly is another type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the assembly that contains the Testing class from your second component. I guess that assembly is MSMQWrite. If you already reference it make sure that is being copied to the folder from where the second component is running so it can be found at runtime.

Other option is to move the actual class being serialised to a different component (e.g. MSMQCommon) and reference it from both your component writing and the one reading. Or just have one component.

Comment: I don't see why I should have to have both methods in a single assembly. The whole point is that in a live environment I have 1 component installed on the sending server and another on the receiving server totally separate physical machines. By making a single component and deploying twice so that each can use the correct method is blatantly wrong. I was assuming that the error message is misleading and that it's something else I'm missing. The only thing that links the components is the message queue. One components method shouldn't need to have a reference to the other components method.

Comment: You are using Binary Formatter so in order to deserialize you need the assembly containing the exact same object that you serialized, hence the shared component (or everything in the same). The all in one component was just a short way of achieving the same. If you want to decouple from a shared class your components you are going to need to use a different Serializer, XML or a custom one, and have your classes in both ways know how to serialize. Moving the DTO to a shared component and deploying it in both way should be the best though.

Comment: Hi I realised what you meant. The DTO needs to be placed in it's own assembly and then referenced by both sender and receiver dll's it now works thanks.